# Can Firebug show CSS comments - would be very helpful when using SASS

Tags: css, comments, firebug

Does anyone know if Firebug can show CSS comments?

When using line numbers output from SASS it would be a huge time saver when debugging.

Sorry if it's easy - just can't find an option or any info on doing this.

Comment: You should seriously check out [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/).

Comment: Thanks for that, looks like what I'm after - I did notice the latest comment saying it doesn't work with Firebug anymore but will give it a go. Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think firebug can do this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it actually can. I was looking for it and found that if you click the `Source Edit` button, then you can view the CSS comments.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays I prefer Firefox's built-in inspector tool, as it doesn't strip css comments.

Your turn, Firebug.

Comment: That's pretty great. One click to jump to definition and then from the comments I know which line in which of the bunch of combined files I need to go to. Firebug shows comments in the "Edit source" mode, but it's very buggy - jumps to wrong line and only works the first time, then does nothing until I refresh the page. Built-in inspector FTW.

Answer (score 1):

If you still prefer to use Firebug then use [FireCompass for Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firecompass-for-firebug/?src=search)